# Is there a hook for when a CiviMail is created/scheduled/sent/completed?

Tags: civimail, email, hooks, logs

I want to call a function whenever a CiviMail is sent from our system, to send a log message to a third party system (Slack in this case).

I've had a look at the CiviCRM documentation, and while I can see hooks for both before/after an *email* is sent, I can't see one for a CiviMailing. I could in theory use these hooks, but even if I de-duplicated it down to a single record, it wouldn't contain information about the mailing (such as mailing name, mailing size, groups, etc).

What's the best option to accomplish this? Is there a relevant hook? Would I need to run a cronjob to check the relevant tables?

Answer (score 1):

to be checked, but creating a mailing should go through the normal hooks like the other entities in civi

so if you go with the pre or post hooks
http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Database+hooks

```
hook_civicrm_post( $op, $objectName, $objectId, &$objectRef )
```

you should have one with the objectname mailing you want to handle and do the needed

Comment: Aha, generic hooks! I'll give it a try and report back.